# End a while loop that is running in a secondary thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I have an application where the user inputs how many times the application should repeat an action. The user inputed value is taken and used in a while loop that repeats the action the user specified amount of times. The process can be very long and I would like to have a button that would allow the user to end the process. I have moved the repeat process to a secondary thread (NSThread) so that the user can continue to interact with the user interface while the process is running. I'm having trouble stopping the repeat process when the user presses the "Stop" button. What is the best way to allow my main thread to communicate to a secondary thread that it needs to stop a while loop running in it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

This didn't seem to work for me... I declared two atomic NSNumbers using @property (atomic, retain). They are both set to have an integer value of 0. Here is my loop that runs in the method run in the secondary thread:

```
 int i = 0;

 while (i < timesToRun && [numberOne intValue] == 0) { 
 [self doSomething]; 
 numberOne = numberTwo;
 i++; 
 }'
```

My stop button calls a method that changes the integer value of numberTwo to "1". For some reason this isn't stopping the loop. Am I doing something incorrectly?

EDIT: Thank you all for your help. After quite a bit of trial and error, I finally found a solution to my problem. I simply created a .strings file that is empty except for the text "NO". I set the text to "NO" when the application is loaded. In my new while loop, I check to see if the value of the file has changed using an NSString stringWithContentsOfFile. When I want to end the loop I call a method that writes to the file and changes the value to "YES". Here's my new loop:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StopFile" ofType:@"strings"];

NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"TheString: %@", theString);

int i;

for (i = 0; i < timesToRunScript && theString == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO"]; i++) {
    [scriptToRun executeAndReturnError:nil];
   NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", theString);
    if (theString == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yes"]) {
        break;
    }
```

Please let me know if you see anything that can be improved. Thanks.

Comment: `atomic` isn't a valid property attribute; it's just the default. You either write `nonatomic` or nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an atomic property on the object performing the while loop, and check the property with each iteration of the loop.

Making the property atomic will make it thread-safe, so that you can change it in one thread, and read it in another.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to check a volatile atomic variable each iteration of your while loop. Your "stop thread" can then set it to a stop value. Your "loop thread" will then check this variable and can stop when it is set.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me... I declared two atomic NSNumbers using @property (atomic, retain). They are both set to have an integer value of 0. Here is my loop that runs in the method: 

' int i = 0;
    
    while (i < timesToRun && [numberOne intValue] == 0) {
        [self doSomething];
        numberOne = numberTwo;
        i++;
    }'
My stop button calls a method that changes the integer value of numberTwo to "1". For some reason this isn't stopping the loop. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Hmmm... NSNumber is immutable, so how do you set that value to 1? Create a new NSNumber? If so, then perhaps the loop is not necessarily referring to the same instance of NSNumber as the other thread that "set it to 1". So the loop may not be aware of any change. As people said, use an atomic (and simple, e.g. int or BOOL) property to mark termination. These are not reference types and don't have such pointer and memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `NSNumber`, use something simple like an atomic `int` or `BOOL` property as a termination marker. Those are not reference types so you don't run any risk of memory issues:

```
@property(assign) BOOL terminateASAP;
```

And in your loop do:

```
for (i = 0; i < timesToRun && !terminateASAP; i++) 
{ 
    [self doSomething]; 
    // etc...

    // if necessary, e.g. because each iteration is slow,
    // add more checks for terminateASAP:
    if (terminateASAP)
        break;

    // more slow code...
}
```

---

FWIW, the line

```
numberOne = numberTwo;
```

looks suspicious. That only copies the pointer, and leaves the old object to which `numberOne` pointed inaccessible, i.e. you'd have a leak.

Comment: `atomic` isn't a valid property attribute. It's just the default; you either specify `nonatomic` or nothing.

Comment: @Josh: while that may be true, it will compile as declared above (at least in Xcode 4.1). It clearly shows the intent, which is better than to simply omit nonatomic, IMO.

Comment: @Josh: I removed it, but it does compile, if specified. Beats me why.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still on 4.0.2. I wonder if there's a compiler difference; it's possible they recently added an `atomic` keyword in order, as you say, to allow intent to be more explicit. A lot of things have been changing lately.

Comment: @Josh: It doesn't show as keyword (plain text colour), but it compiles. So I don't think it is a keyword, but it seems to be ignored. I tried other identifiers (e.g. green, blah, etc.), and the compiler does complain about them, but not about atomic.

Comment: @Rudy Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate it. For some reason, even with the atomic BOOL, my secondary thread is not reflecting the changed BOOL value. Thus, my loop is not exiting. I just can't seem to get the secondary thread to pick up a change made in the main thread... If you have any other suggestions that would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the same BOOL, on the same object? The atomic BOOL property should be a property of the thread that ought to be stopped. Could you post the declaration of the thread object and the implementation of the loop? Also post how you call it. If it is too much, post it to a dedicated site for posting code.

Comment: @Rudy, I was wondering if you might provide some insight into whether or not the way I found to stop the loop is alright. I posted my revised code in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you serious? You create a file as some kind of semaphore instead of simply setting a simple BOOL? Why don't you try to find out why setting a simple BOOL is not noticed in your loop, instead?

Comment: I was pretty stumped as to why the atomic BOOL wasn't operating correctly. I spent a couple of days trying different ways to make the atomic properties work and I really wasn't making much, if any, progress. Do you believe using the file will have any negative affect on the application? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: A file is a global thing, i.e. just as bad as a global variable. It is actually what you would avoid when using threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `volatile int` instead of the two `NSNumber` objects.  The compiler is probably optimizing away `numberOne = numberTwo`, thinking that it cannot change during the execution of the loop, or something like that.